# Azure DevOps Sprints: "Capacity" tab missing

Tags: azure, capacity-planning

I have encountered an issue with the Capacity tab missing on the Sprints page. All team members are in the Contributors group and team Admins as well (the group is used to measure PMs capacity thus all of us have the Team Admin rights).

In the Project Settings/Team configuration/Areas/.../Security - edit access was granted as well.

However, a couple of team members with team admin rights and one with Project Admin rights cannot see the Capacity tab on the Sprints page.

Any help?